# Suspension or suspensions

Tags: uncountable-nouns

What is the difference between suspension and suspensions?

I know suspensions is the plural form for dispersion but in what circumstances the word "suspensions" can be used in a sentence.

"Suspensions containing only water and PEG40S were also prepared."

Why the author used plural form of suspension?

Comment: Presumably the author is describing a situation where the experimenter created multiple vials or beakers (or whatever) of water-and-PEG40S solutions. The contents of each one of these fluid-filled containers can be called "a suspension"—so it follows that the lot of them can be called "suspensions."

Answer (score -1):

In your example sentence *"Suspensions"* is referred to as the system of springs that acts as shock absorbers in vehicles. The plural form is used because the author is talking about multiple suspensions.

> The rear suspension of this vehicle is faulty.
>
> Suspensions are needed in this prototype model.

Comment: Hello, Ashish. You've got the wrong polyseme here. The chemistry-related sense is involved (see Sven's comment).